# Android Library: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: android, classnotfoundexception

I need some help resolving an issue I am experiencing in Android. I have an AAR Library which has a JAR embedded in it. The lib is called TSSLib and the JAR which is embedded in it is called Pebble.

I have used this Library in other applications but in my latest application I am getting a DexPathList error. See the logcat below.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.owen.myfirstapplication, PID: 2541
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lza/co/techss/pebble/Pebble;
    at za.co.techss.tsslib.pebble_classes.fpebbles.FPebble.getPebble(FPebble.java:20)
    at za.co.techss.tsslib.pebble_classes.fpebbles.FPMenu.setMenuTestName(FPMenu.java:64)
    at za.co.techss.tsslib.pebble_classes.fpebbles.FPMenu.setMenuCaption(FPMenu.java:131)
    at com.example.owen.myfirstapplication.MainActivity.<clinit>(MainActivity.java:17)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1572)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1065)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2199)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)

    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "za.co.techss.pebble.Pebble" on path: DexPathList[[dex file "/data/data/com.example.owen.myfirstapplication/files/instant-run/dex/slice-support-annotations-23.0.0_7098173c187ce97e6c8e0e5ed251f5cec7ba814b-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.owen.myfirstapplication/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_9-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.owen.myfirstapplication/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_8-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.owen.myfirstapplication/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_7-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.owen.myfirstapplication/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_6-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.owen.myfirstapplication/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_5-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.owen.myfirstapplication/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_4-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.owen.myfirstapplication/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_3-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.owen.myfirstapplication/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_2-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.owen.myfirstapplication/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_1-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.owen.myfirstapplication/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_0-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.owen.myfirstapplication/files/instant-run/dex/slice-internal_impl-23.0.0_20b69c5a7d9459fb495e50940c3ff3c34c562b52-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.owen.myfirstapplication/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.android.support-support-v4-23.0.0_07957f4ba1b3cfc5a3b6ff6cbaad9d5567e413fd-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.owen.myfirstapplication/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.android.support-appcompat-v7-23.0.0_12b550572c817a2cdd144744ac50da1530814fcf-classes.dex"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
    at com.android.tools.fd.runtime.IncrementalClassLoader$DelegateClassLoader.findClass(IncrementalClassLoader.java:90)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
    at za.co.techss.tsslib.pebble_classes.fpebbles.FPebble.getPebble(FPebble.java:20) 
    at za.co.techss.tsslib.pebble_classes.fpebbles.FPMenu.setMenuTestName(FPMenu.java:64) 
    at za.co.techss.tsslib.pebble_classes.fpebbles.FPMenu.setMenuCaption(FPMenu.java:131) 
    at com.example.owen.myfirstapplication.MainActivity.<clinit>(MainActivity.java:17) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1572) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1065) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2199) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694) 
    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "za.co.techss.pebble.Pebble" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.owen.myfirstapplication-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
    at ja
```

I have also included my Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.owen.myfirstapplication">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Android app manifest:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.owen.myfirstapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
    compile project(':tsslib')
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.owen.myfirstapplication;

import android.util.Log;

import za.co.techss.tsslib.components.ComponentRoot;
import za.co.techss.tsslib.pebble_classes.fpebbles.FPMenu;

public class MainActivity extends ComponentRoot
{
    private static FPMenu menuPebble;

    static
    {
        try
        {
            menuPebble = new FPMenu();
            menuPebble.setMenuCaption("Main Menu");

            menuPebble.setMenuOption("Jobcard", GroupWizardProcess.class, "menu_contact_group");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("MainActivity", "-----> Error in static constructor!", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void wStart() throws Exception
    {

    }

    @Override
    public int wComponentResourceLayout() {return R.layout.activity_main;}
}
```

I am not sure what is causing the issue or how to resolve it. I have tried several of the fixes recommended on StackOverflow but none seem to fix the issue.

Android Studio Version: 2.2.2

I will appreciate any help.

Thank you

Comment: post your activity here

Comment: @AnandSavjani I have updated and added the MainActivity. I forgot to include it. Thank you